# How to select specific cells in the target sheet, not the entire sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a log to track changes in a sheet. But i just want to select specific cells to track in the target sheet, currently my code provided below track the changes in the entire sheet. If someone could help me modify my code below to be able to do that, it would be so helpul. Thanks!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values     (before UnDo)
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Log  - Inputs - Divisions")
    Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
 
      'sh.Unprotect "" 'it should be good to protect the sheet
     If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet      Name")

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it   faster)
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
     If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
        TgValue = extractData(Target)
     Else
        TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Formula, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or  as a string for a single cell)
        boolOne = True
     End If
     Application.EnableEvents = False                                'avoiding to trigger the change event   after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                           'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                            'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
     Application.EnableEvents = True

     Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
     For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
        If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
            sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).Formula = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
        End If
     Next r
 
    'sh.Protect ""
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
For Each El In arr
    sh.Range(El(1)).Formula = El(0)
Next
End Sub

Function extractData(rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
        For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
            arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Formula, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
        Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
type here
```

Comment: `If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("YourRangeAddressHere")) Then`.

Comment: You can add non-contiguous cells and ranges with one line like this: `set rng = range("A1:B4,D44,F55")`

Comment: @BigBen Missing the "Is Nothing" there? You'd get an error if it's outside the specified range.

Comment: @Notus_Panda yes it's Monday lol.